# How to change my string with dot to int in python

Tags: python, string, integer

I need to change my string to int but my string have dot amd i dont know how

```
Mystring = "10.00"

print(int(Mystring))
```

Comment: Perhaps convert it to a float first? `print(int(float(Mystring)))`

Comment: Try this: `print(int(Mystring.split(".")[0]))`